# Go GZIP Flush and Determining Size

Tags: go, gzip

I am creating GZIPs on demand by streaming data, but I need to split it because the receving end has a hard code limit. When I Flush() and Close(), I see that the underyling byte buffer grows by 13 bytes. I looked at the source code of Gzip Close:

```
func (z *Writer) Close() error {
    if z.err != nil {
        return z.err
    }
    if z.closed {
        return nil
    }
    z.closed = true
    if !z.wroteHeader {
        z.Write(nil)
        if z.err != nil {
            return z.err
        }
    }
    z.err = z.compressor.Close()
    if z.err != nil {
        return z.err
    }
    le.PutUint32(z.buf[:4], z.digest)
    le.PutUint32(z.buf[4:8], z.size)
    _, z.err = z.w.Write(z.buf[:8])
    return z.err
}
```

It indeed writes something but is there someway to determine it more pragmatic than just saying 13 bytes? There can be headers etc. I just want to have a safe margin, is there any possibilities that it can grow way larger than 13 bytes? I can happily set 1kb margin and live with it.

Comment: That's weird, buffer should be only 8 bytes larger, because of gzip footer: 4 for the checksum and 4 for the original data size.

Comment: You could wrap your gzip writer into another, "chunk buffering" writer, which would collect data in chunks of your predefined size and as soon as it collected that much or more, pass it downstream.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 13 bytes are the maximum value to my knowledge. 8 bytes come from the gzip footer, the two `PutUint32` calls.
The other 5 bytes are added by the huffmann compressor which ads an empty final block when the compressor is closed. It will add 3 bits (= 1 byte) for the final block header and 2 bytes for the length `0` and another 2 bytes which are inverted length `0xffff`. So i assume you can calculate with those 13 bytes.

Comment: the 3 are bits the other two bytes, i'll clarify it in the answer

Comment: Sorry, I completely misread that sentence, you did have bits there ;)

Answer (score 2):

A conservative upper bound for the gzip-compressed output is:

`n + ((n + 7) >> 3) + ((n + 63) >> 6) + 23`

where `n` is the size of the input in bytes.

Comment: I know you are author of zlib but that's very conservative :)

Comment: In the limit that's only 14% over the input. If you're so limited on memory that that 14% is an issue, then you have other problems. If you know exactly what parameters are being provided to zlib, then you may be able to get it down to about 0.03%, plus 26 bytes.